# How to prevent the component from reinit when the route changes in angular 9 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component where a chart `width` is stored in a variable (can't use style. it's for `d3`). However, whenever I change the route, all variables in this class component get `undefined` values.

I tried to `ngIf`, services(they go undefined, too), use `ngOnDestroy()` (it doesn't get called when routeing changes)

Here is my code with more explanation.

component class:

You can see the variable `setWidth` which keeps track of the `width` of the `d3` chart and it goes `undefined` when route changes and I'm not sure because of `ngOnChange` because `HostListener` detects window resize and resize the `width` accordingly even if it breaks after a route change.

```
export class BrushBarChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges 
{
  @Input() timeSeriesData: Object;
  @ViewChild('timeSeriesChart', { static: true }) private timeSeriesChart: ElementRef;
  setWidth: number;
  
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.render();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onScreenResize () {
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    let divWidth = this.timeSeriesChart.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    if (divWidth === 0) {
      divWidth = this.setWidth;
    } else {
      this.setWidth = divWidth;
    }
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 90, left: 40 },
    margin2 = { top: 130, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  }
}
```

Here is the template:

```js
<div id="timeSeriesChart" #timeSeriesChart *ngIf="DestroyHide"></div>
```

Here is how the route file deals with the change route request. Cannot post the whole code on the file.

```
{ 
  path: 'delete',  
  loadChildren: () => import('app/delete/delete.module').then(m => m.deleteModule), 
  canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
  data: {preload: true}
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say why that happening, because it is unclear what routes relations are, maybe this component should unload and get destroyed.

Comment: Please tell, is your original problem just is because render called before html created and timeSeriesChart has no width? Cause im not sure why you need to create such variable.

Comment: The problem is that he's when a component loads... the setWith will be undefined. It will only ever get a value if `timeSeriesData` changes or if the screen is resized. He needs to implement it in such a way that `setWidth` gets a value when the component initializes... which is basically the intial `offsetWidth` of `timeSeriesChart.nativeElement`.

Comment: @MosiaThabo exactly because of this stroing this variable has no sense - offsetWidth anyway queried each render call, no sense to store it and call offsetWidth again next time.

Comment: You may want to because it might be a viable he's using inside the template. Or perhaps somewhere within that class. I wouldn't worry about what he does with it, imagine having to call `this.timeSeriesChart.nativeElement.offsetWidth` everywhere where he wants to use that value?

Comment: Its D3 chart, there is nothing to use in template multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember how `ngOnChanges()`. On your case, this method will run when you input boad data changes. I am referring to this  `@Input() timeSeriesData: Object;`

So basically, `ngOnChanges()` is called when `timeSeriesData` is changed. it isn't triggered by route change.

---

**Suggestion:**

You might want to run your `render()` on `ngOnInit()`, because this is done once when the component loads. So basically changes to your variables will then only happen when you resize or change the value of the input.

You might want to look at [this](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) and [this](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/exploring-angular-lifecycle-hooks-onchanges) for more info on these life cycle methods. You will find the articles helpful.